# Get parent of all matching value in JSON using jq

Tags: json, aws, jq

I am new to jq and I have a scenario to get the parent(at a particular level) of any matching value in the json file. Below is the sample data.

```
{
    "DevOps": {
        "us-east-1": {
            "i-049aa9a3bddb4****": {
                "AmiLaunchIndex": 0,
                "ImageId": "ami-00068cd7555f543d5",
                "InstanceId": "i-049aa9a3bddb4*****",
                "InstanceType": "t2.nano",
                "LaunchTime": "2019-11-24 18:39:25+00:00",
                "Monitoring": {
                    "State": "disabled"
                },
                "Placement": {
                    "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-1a",
                    "GroupName": "",
                    "Tenancy": "default"
                },
                "PrivateDnsName": "ip-10-250-128-77.ec2.internal",
                "PrivateIpAddress": "10.250.128.77",
                "ProductCodes": [],
                "PublicDnsName": "",
                "Tags": [
                    {
                        "Key": "Name",
                        "Value": "Network-Test-Host"
                    }
                ],

            },
            "i-0368117434*****": {
                "AmiLaunchIndex": 0,
                "ImageId": "ami-078137ecf12552edf",
                "InstanceId": "i-0368117434******",
                "InstanceType": "c5.2xlarge",
                "KeyName": "infra-systems-prod-key",
                "LaunchTime": "2020-02-13 15:51:15+00:00",
                "Monitoring": {
                    "State": "disabled"
                },
                "Placement": {
                    "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-1a",
                    "GroupName": "",
                    "Tenancy": "default"
                },
                "PrivateDnsName": "ip-10-250-138-161.ec2.internal",
                "PrivateIpAddress": "10.250.138.161",
                "ProductCodes": [],
                "PublicDnsName": "",
                "Tags": [
                    {
                        "Key": "Name",
                        "Value": "Network-Test-Host"
                    }
                ],

            },
        }
    }
}
```

For example, if my search value is "10.250.128.77", it should fetch the parent - "i-049aa9a3bddb4****". if the value is "Network-Test-Host", it should give me the list of 2 instance ids(i-049aa9a3bddb4****, i-0368117434*****). Then from this point, I would be able to traverse at any key and get the respective value like the hostname, ImageId, Instance Type

Any help on this is much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Your query using a particular private IP address:

```bash
jq '.DevOps."us-east-1" | map_values(select( .PrivateIpAddress == "10.250.128.77" ))' file
```

Parametrised to take the query IP address from the command line arguments:

```bash
jq --arg addr 10.250.128.77 \
    '.DevOps."us-east-1" | map_values(select( .PrivateIpAddress == $addr ))' file
```

Your query using a particular `Key` tag's `Value`:

```bash
jq '.DevOps."us-east-1" | map_values(select( IN(.Tags[]; {Key: "Name", Value: "Network-Test-Host"}) ))' file
```

Parametrised to take the `Key` and the `Value` from the command line arguments:

```bash
jq --arg Key Name --arg Value Network-Test-Host \
    '.DevOps."us-east-1" | map_values(select( IN(.Tags[]; $ARGS.named) ))' file
```

These commands would generate a JSON document with a single object containing the keys+values from your input document's `.DevOps."us-east-1"` section that matches the queries.

Common for each command is that they apply a `select()` statement to the values of the `.DevOps."us-east-1"` section.  The boolean expression will be different depending on what subsection you want to test with the query.  The sections where the boolean expression evaluates to *true* will be kept while all other bits are removed.